# Transaction in mongo with Nestjs do not work

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, orm, nestjs

I want to make a transaction and I am using findOneAndUpdate I get the following error: "MongoServerError: Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos". What I can do ?

app.module.ts:

```
imports...

@Module({
  imports: [
    ...,
    MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.URL_DATABASE, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      retryAttempts: 2,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

my.service.ts:

```
import { Connection } from "mongoose"

export class MyService {
 constructor(
    @InjectModel(User.name)
    private userModel: Model<UserDocument>,
    @InjectConnection() private readonly connection: Connection,
  ) {}
}

async delete(idPa: string): Promise<boolean> {
 let result = false;
 const session = await this.connection.startSession();

 try {
      await session.withTransaction(async () => {
        await this.userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
          { _id: idPa },
          { status: false },
          { session },
        );
      });

      result = true;
    } finally {
      await session.endSession();
    }
}
```

As a result when running my service from the controller I get: **MongoServerError: Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, it turns out that I must make an additional configuration to my database which is the "replica set".

**Follow these steps:**

1. Install mongosh
2. Create 3 directories.
3. Perform these commands:

```
mongosh –-dbpath "C:\data1\db" –-port 27017 --replSet rs0 --bind_ip 127.0.0.1
```

```
mongosh –-dbpath "C:\data2\db" –-port 27018 --replSet rs0 --bind_ip 127.0.0.1
```

```
mongosh –-dbpath "C:\data3\db" –-port 27019 --replSet rs0 --bind_ip 127.0.0.1
```

**Note: For each of these commands open a new cmd**

4. Open a new cmd and open the parent directory: `cmd mongosh --port 27017`

Once inside. Follow these steps.

1. `rs.initiate()`
2. `rs.reconfig({ _id: "rs0", members: [{ _id: 0, host: "127.0.0.1:27017" }, { _id: 1, host: "127.0.0.1:27018" }, { _id: 2, host: "127.0.0.1:27019" }] }, {force:true});`

**Then go to the child nodes, 27018 and 27019 and add the following commands.**

node 27018 go steps:

1. `mongosh --port 27018`
2. `db.getMongo().setReadPref('secondary')`

node 27019 go steps:

1. `mongosh --port 27019`
2. `db.getMongo().setReadPref('secondary')`

Finally, execute the transaction again, my app.module.ts remains exactly the same, remember that the local connection will always be **127.0.0.1**

Comment: Another error I encountered when restarting the nodes is: "Error parsing command line: unrecognized option: --replSet". The solution is the following, I went to the mongod bin directory, in my case the path was the following: "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin" and opened a cmd as administrator. I went to the path "cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin" and ran the nodes again with the following commands: "start mongod -replSet rs0 --dbpath "C:\data1\db" -- port 27017" and do the same for the others.